# Failed to load buffer (.bin) - Three.JS

Tags: webpack, three.js, blender

All the solutions for this problem seem to be the same - Put the .gltf & the .bin files in the same folder and then try.
I have done this but im still getting this error and ive no idea as to why.

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader()
let mesh;

loader.load( './zippedFolder', function ( gltf ) {
  mesh = gltf.scene

  })
```

And the two files reside in a zipped folder.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just ask the GLTFLoader to open a `.zip` file. It says [in the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader):

> A loader for glTF 2.0 resources.

... not for `.zip`  files.

You have to deliver both the `.gltf` and the `.bin` in their natural state. What you could do, however, is get your server to deliver assets [with GZIP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip), which your browser knows to decompress automatically. But that's something that's handled in your server settings, not by manually converting to a `.zip` file.

**Update**: All you have to do is point the loader to the `.gltf` file, which contains a reference to the `.bin` file within. You can open it in a text editor, and you'll see something like this, the `buffers.uri` property has the path to the accompanying binary so the loader knows where to look for it:

```
"buffers" : [
    {
        "byteLength" : 69340,
        "uri" : "alloy.bin"
    }
]
```

Comment: Is this standard? I havent seen any examples of people doing this - Normally they just have the GLTF file and it works

Comment: Yes, look at [the source code in this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=gltf#webgl_loader_gltf): `loader.load( 'DamagedHelmet.gltf', ...` it points to a `.gltf` file, not a zipped folder. Look at the code example [in the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader), it points directly to the file with `.gltf` extension.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that - It seems they are just using a plain old .gltf file? I have done this before with a GLTF file and it worked fine, This particular model tells me that it cannot find the .bin file when i try that though

Comment: Ah, I see where the confusion comes from. I updated the answer with an explanation. You just have to direct the loader to the `.gltf` which itself contains the reference to the `.bin` so the loader can find it.

Comment: I had a look in the file and it turns out i already had this pointing to the bin file but im still being told the same thing. Is this a webpack issue?

Comment: we have to use webpack to load and serve the .bin file related to the gltf